# Overlay icon over relative layout in Drawer layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-relativelayout, navigation-drawer

I want to integrate a button over relative layout over navigation drawer. Could someone help me please?

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rela"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"></RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/radiobutton_off_background"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"

        />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My floatin button appear inside. But cannot able to overlay it

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit about what you're expecting and what you're actually seeing? Maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: I Think i am doing wrong . I was trying to put fragment inside navigation drawer . Which i think is not going to work . My question was related to add a handle to pull navigation drawer. This is the link which was looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223141/sliding-one-fragment-over-another-in-android